# Unable to turn ON bluetooth in ubuntu xorg 17.10

Tags: bluetooth

I'm not able to turn ON bluetooth in Ubuntu 14.04. I recently upgraded to 17.10 and the problem still exists. [I have toggled it to ON but bluetooth still remains off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeM45.png)

rfkill list returns

```
rfkill list

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)

    Subsystem: Lenovo AR8162 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3979]

    Kernel driver in use: alx

    Kernel modules: alx

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:051b]

    Kernel driver in use: wl

    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2e1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

[    0.082896] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

[    6.525002] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x450f02)

[ 4929.014970] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22


[ 4929.014993] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized

[ 4929.014996] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized

[ 4929.014999] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized

[ 4929.015003] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

If I give bluetoothctl  all I'm receiving is 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...

I would really appreciate some help.Let me know if anymore info is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the BCM4313 adapter in your output supports both wi-fi and bluetooth. Do you have package `linux-firmware` installed`?  (You can check using `dpkg -l linux-firmware`).

Comment: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
ii  linux-firmware                  1.169.2              all                  Firmware for Linux kernel drivers

Comment: That is the response I got for the command.

Comment: I have the same issue too now... did you end up solving this?